# Неработает цикл for в цикле while что делать? питон

Tags: python, sqlite3

Вот рабочий код:

```
qwe = 0
for value in cursor.execute(f"SELECT Date_msk FROM time_bd WHERE Num_bd = {qwe}"):
     print(value)
```

Консоль:

```
12345
```

Но мне нужно поставить этот цикл в цикл while:

```
qwe = 0
while True:
    
    qwe += 1

    for value in cursor.execute(f"SELECT Date_msk FROM time_bd WHERE Num_bd = {qwe}"):
             print(value)
    else: 
        print("Не работает")
```

Консоль:

```
Не работает
```

Comment: у вас в первом случае qwe = 0 а во втором уже qwe = 1

Comment: По-моему у вас лишний tab во втором варианте